# what is this error after submit formData in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

when i'm sending image with text data than showing this Error:

```
    VM83:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON
```

here is my code :

```
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(pname,pimg,pdesc)
        let formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append('pname', pname)
        formdata.append('pimg', pimg)
        formdata.append('pdesc', pdesc)
        console.log(formdata)
        const result = await fetch("http://localhost/ecomapi/addProduct.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body:formdata
        })
        result = await result.json();
        console.log(result)
    }
```

i'm trying to insert data with api .

Answer (score 1):

The data returned from the api is not well-formed json, so when you attempt to parse it as a json object with:

```
result = await result.json();
```

...it throws an error.

Log the return from the api directly and use an online json validator like: https://jsonlint.com/ to see where the error is in greater detail.

Read about .json() and streams: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a json response from the php file?
If its like:

```
echo 'working!';
```

change the js to:

```
result = await result.text;
```

they should match

Answer (score -1):

Remove headers or in headers Content-Type

```
 headers: {
            
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
```

without headers you can submit form data. and also check your api page may be have there sql problem